# PHPMailer error handling request

Tags: php, forms, hotmail

I've updated this code, using PHPMailer. The code now works and sends through the form to any email address I wish as long as I have the correct host setup in the PHP. This is GREAT. But, it doesn't direct me to my thank you page: `header("Location: http://strawberryletting.co.uk/new_form/thank_you.html");` it sends the email fine, along with the correct information, but once the user selects the `submit button` they stay on the PHP page with a lot of written jargon. Please see updated PHP below:

PHP:

```
    <?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");  // Look for errors and report errors - if there are any

$name = $_POST["name"];  // Declare variables - inputted from HTML form 
$email = $_POST["email"];
$tel = $_POST["tel"];
$msg = $_POST["msg"];


require("PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php"); // Call files required for the phpmailer code from our folder directory
require("PHPMailer/src/Exception.php");
require("PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP(); // Simple mail transfer protocol
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // 1 - 4 use 2 - most useful response
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable the SMTP authentication
$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com'; // SMTP server and backup server  
$mail->Username = 'billy.farroll@hotmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'PASSWORD';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // enable encryption - accepts TLS also  
$mail->Port = 587; // port to connect - SSL 465 TLS TLS 587 - likely port numbers - 25, 465 or 587
$mail->setFrom('billy.farroll@hotmail.com', 'Billy Farroll'); // This is where the email will come from 
$mail->addAddress('billy@strawberrymarketing.com','Billy Farroll'); // This is where the email will be sent to
$mail->addReplyTo("$email","$name"); 
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'TEST1';
$mail->Body = "$msg"; 
if (!$mail->send()){ // Send the message 

    echo 'Message Failed';


    } else {


        header("Location: http://strawberryletting.co.uk/new_form/thank_you.html"); // Take me to Thank you page 

    }

?>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">

<section id="contact">
    <form action="enquiry_new.php" method="post">
          <div class="field name-box">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Who Are You?" tabindex="1" required>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <span>Done</span>
          </div>

          <div class="field email-box">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="name@email.com" tabindex="2" required>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <span>Done</span>
          </div>

      <div class="field tel-box">
                <input type="text" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Telephone Number" tabindex="3" required>
                <label for="tel">Mobile</label>
                <span>Done</span>
          </div>

          <div class="field msg-box">
                <textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="4" placeholder="What's Up?" tabindex="4" required></textarea>
                <label for="msg">Message</label>
                <span>Done</span>
          </div>

          <input class="button" type="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
</section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use one of the tried and tested mail libraries like PHPMailer, SwiftMailer or similar instead of using the low level `mail()`-function. That will not just give you a way more verbose API, it will also be a breeze to send the email through your email providers SMTP server instead. The script will also be more portable that way (since it won't depend on your web servers configuration)

Comment: Magnus Eriksson Have updated with the PHPMailer library, would you possibly be able to see my new PHP and see the problem? Would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Have you gone through all the points in the duplicate question?

Comment: One thing I can say is that your code should spit out a bunch of "undefined index"-notices. Your using `$_POST['$email']`, `$_POST['$name']` etc when it should be `$_POST['email']`, `$_POST['name']` and so on (without the `$` in front of the keys). You've even used the correct names in the beginning of the file and stored the data in variables, so I'm not sure why you're using the `$_POST`-variable at all later in the script.

Comment: Yes I have been through majority of the other points in the other question. So you would have the $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['$email'], $_POST['$name']); and $mail->Body = $_POST['$msg'];  like so: $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']); and $mail->Body = $_POST['msg']; ?

Comment: Or just remove the $_POST variable completely?

Comment: Just use the variables you've defined in the beginning instead

Comment: Thanks, will do a couple more tests.

Comment: Sorry to keep pestering you Magnus. I've updated the code to the latest PHPMailer and it works. But, doesn't direct me to the thank you page.

Comment: FIXED IT FINALLY.